# close() was never explicitely called on database

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

I'm writing a music player and I'm getting this error despite using songsdb.close() when recreating the music database.

UpdateDB.java:reloadDB():

```
public void reloadDB (View v) {
        status.setText(getText(R.string.updatedb_text_status_init));
        loadSongsFromFile();
        status.setText(getText(R.string.updatedb_text_status_recdb));
        this.getDatabasePath("songs").delete();
        SongsDBOpenHelper sdboh = new SongsDBOpenHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
        SQLiteDatabase songsdb = sdboh.getWritableDatabase();
        status.setText(getText(R.string.updatedb_text_status_fildb));
        songsdb.beginTransaction();
        for (String s : songs) {
            AudioFile af = new AudioFile(new File(s));
            songsdb.execSQL("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO artists (name) VALUES (\"" + af.getMetadata()[1] + "\")");
            Cursor c = songsdb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM artists WHERE name = \"" + af.getMetadata()[1] + "\";", null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            songsdb.execSQL("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO albums (name, artist) VALUES (\"" + af.getMetadata()[2] + "\", \"" + c.getInt(0) + "\")");
            c = songsdb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM albums WHERE name = \"" + af.getMetadata()[2] + "\";", null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            songsdb.execSQL("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO songs (name, album, file) VALUES (\"" + af.getMetadata()[0] + "\", \"" + c.getInt(0) + "\", \"" + af.getFileString() + "\")");
            Log.d("Song", af.getMetadata()[0]);
        }
        status.setText(getText(R.string.updatedb_text_status_finishing));
        songsdb.setTransactionSuccessful();
        songsdb.endTransaction();
        songsdb.close();
        sdboh.close();
        this.finish();
    }
```

SongsDBOpenHelper:onCreate():

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE songs (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, name VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE, album INTEGER, file VARCHAR(100));");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE albums (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, name VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE, artist INTEGER);");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE artists (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, name VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE);");
}
```

The class `AudioFile` doesn't use any databases.

And I know I'm using `rawQuery` the wrong way...

**EDIT:**

After adding the try/catch-blocks, this problem was solved. But I'm getting other errors for every existent song:

```
Failure 10 (Disk I/O error) on 0x1f5738 when executing 'INSERT OR IGNORE ...'
```

Where does this come from?

Comment: Put all your effort in try-catch block and close your db in catch block also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this error once.  It is not the DB that needs to be explicitly closed.  It is the Cursor you get from a query.

Comment: If you read my edit, I've solved the initial problem. I've added `c.close();` in the for-loop

Comment: No.  You made no mention of that.  All you say is you added a try/catch block.  If you want people to help you, you need to be explicit about what you have done and need help with.